# How to create fog similar to this map in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm learning about a 3d game on unity. I see on the map there is a fog effect. Can anyone explain to me how to create a fog effect like this example
[this is the fog from the example i'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R72LD.png)

Comment: Hey, Not to be rude but have to try to search for the solution for this online I'm sure you'll be able to find something from which you can advance.

Comment: look at this in [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/Manual/PostProcessing-Fog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Rendering -> Lightning and follow the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRYk8.png

Comment: Thank you that was usefull for me thank